# OnAppear method getting called when picker returns from selection

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-picker

In my swiftUI app, the `onAppear` method of my view is getting called when a picker I have in the same view returns from picking. I do not want my `.onAppear` method to be called except when the view loads. Is there an option or a good alternative to `.onAppear` that only gets called when the view loads? Thanks.

Comment: Term "loads" is not applicable to view in SwiftUI. We can react on "create" in `init`, on insert/remove to/from view hierarchy in "onApplear/onDisapear", on render in "body". That's pretty all about life-cycle, which in majority of cases we do not control.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround for this issue. The following code will only call the rest of the `.onAppear` method once, ensuring that it is only called the first time.

```swift
struct SampleView: View{
@State var alreadyDone = false

var body: some View{
Text("Content goes here")
.onAppear{
if !alreadyDone{
//Perform actions for view load
alreadyDone = true
}
}
}

}
```

Comment: I already do this, thanks for the answer.